# Read a .pfm file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, disparity-mapping

I am currently working on a disparity map estimation project in Matlab. I am using the middlebury datasets including ground-truth disparities in PFM format. I don't know how to load this particular format in Matlab. Could anyone help me? Thanks

I have tried a simple load and then read in the documentation that the load function does not support the pfm format.

Comment: The [HDR Toolbox](https://github.com/banterle/HDR_Toolbox) has some code for reading `*.pfm` files.